# Get record from another sheet when value selected from dropdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007

I have **`two sheets`**. 1) `Orders` And 2) `Products`

**`Orders :`**

```
  A             B                 C            D           E
Sr No      particulars         quantity       rate       amount
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1         Dropdown from          
           Products B2:B50 
------------------------------------------------------------------
 2         Dropdown from
           Products B2:B50 
------------------------------------------------------------------

....... And So On.....
```

**`Products :`**

```
 A                    B                   C
---------------------------------------------
Sr No          ProductName             Rate
---------------------------------------------
1               ABC                    440
2               DEF                    210
3               XYZ                    185
   ...... And SO On...
```

In Orders Sheet, In Particulars, Dropdown box is generated with productnames in Products Sheet with Data Validation.

I want to **autofill Rate** of Product Selected from dropdown in **`Orders`** sheet

I tried `VLOOKUP`... But without success

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your "Product" sheet it will not be duplicated a Vlookup works.
For instance ABC remains 440 as rate? Then you can have your "quantity" x "rate" to get your amount. What have your tried in Vlookup and what error?

Comment: quantity X rate for amount is set. I want to autofill 440 in rate in Orders sheet if ABC is selected in particulars.....

Comment: Try this =VLOOKUP(@$B:$B,Product!$B:$C,2,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Orders sheet cell D2

```
=VLOOKUP($B$2,Product!$B:$C,2,FALSE)
```